# Fetch the Month from yyy-MM-dd String

Tags: java, android, date

I have a date string "2012-01-26" which I get from JSON.

I have to now check if the month and year is as current year than display data it in ListView.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-DD");
  try {
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
      c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(event_start_date));
      int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      System.out.println("month is"+month);
 }
```

Year value is always correct, but the Month is always zero.What am I missing guys?

Comment: Note: I don't want the current year or date, but I want the date and year from the String for e.g"2012-12-28".

Right now from the above code I get 

Year=2012;
Month=0;
Date=not checked yet.

Comment: Update: The terrible date-time classes you are using have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching month using Calendar's instance.

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

So you will get current month (i.e. January)
And it means 0. So the result is correct.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#onDateChanged%28android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

month - The month that was set (0-11) for compatibility with [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

If you want the month of `event_start_date`, then you won't have to use calendar's instance at all.

You can fetch it using

```
int month = event_start_date.getMonth();
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are right is there any way I can  get "2012-01-26" month and year from the this String

Comment: @Asmi, why do you parse event_start_date? You can use event_start_date.getMonth().

Comment: But the event_start_date is String , how can I get .getMonth() from it? I m getting this String form JSON, not as a Date but as a String

Comment: @Asmi, ok. If the event_start_date string is in YYYY-MM-DD format, you can add these lines: String[] event_start_d = event_start_date.split("-");
  int month = Integer.parseInt(event_start_d[1]);

Comment: it works:) Splitting it seems very good option.:) Thanks alot

Comment: @Asmi, But I just tried your code. It seems that it will work perfectly if you replace "yyyy-MM-DD" with "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.YearMonth`

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

If you are focused on the year and month without the day, use `YearMonth` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2012-01-26" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
int y = ym.getYear() ;
Month m = ym.getMonth() ;
String monthName = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for posting the modern answer. Please also add the links for backporting `java.time` API and also for using `java.time` API in Android via desugaring.

Answer (score 1):

monthes start from 0 - which means youre getting JANUARY.
from Calendar.java:

```
public final static int JANUARY = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The month is zero based (January = 0) so you have to add one.

Answer (score 1):

read the java doc ;)

for MONTH it says:

```
Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because month in Calendar start from 0 (for January) and go on till 11 (for December)